# Get images from server

Tags: php, image-upload

I uploaded image to the server using php.And i also generate a random image number after the id.Now the name of the uploaded image  like 6_1.jpg, 5_4.jpg etc, Where 1st number is the id (before _) and other is randomly generated number(after _). My codes are as below

```
function upload_receipt_img(){
    $random_digit = rand(0,9);          
    $receipt_id = $_POST['id'];      
        if (isset($_POST['data_url'])) {      
            $file = $receipt_id._.$random_digit.'.jpg';
            $img = substr($_POST['data_url'], strpos($_POST['data_url'], ",") + 1);
            $decodedData = base64_decode($img);
            $success = file_put_contents('assets/receipt_img/' . $file, $decodedData);
            //resize main image
            $source_path = "assets/receipt_img/" . $file;
            $destination = "assets/receipt_img/" . $file;
            $newwidth = 350;
            $this->resizeImg($newwidth, $source_path, $destination);
            $data['img'] = 'assets/receipt_img/' . $receipt_id.$random_digit.'.jpg';
        }
    $this->closeConnection();
    echo $receipt_id;

}
```

Now how can i show images from the server to my home page.Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: add direct url in <img src=""> or save it db and upload dir then use path

Comment: You should store `$data['img']` in DB

Comment: @RakeshSharma I want to show the images dynamically..

Comment: @KallolPratim what do you mean show the image dynamically? you mean something like `<img src="image.php?id=1">`?

Comment: @LatheesanKanes, Yes but i want to use javascript to show all images

Comment: How do you mean? your question/requirement isn't clear. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @LatheesanKanes, I am tring to retrieve all the images dynamically from the server that i uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use header function as

```
<?php 
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
  readfile($destination); // image file path
?>
```

for each image.